# How to set not changable Track color on Slider, React Native

Tags: react-native, slider

Im trying to make a `Slider` from `'@react-native-community/slider'`.

Sadly documentation gives only two options, and its to set `maximumTrackTintColor` and `minimumTrackTintColor`. This properties change the Track color on drag.

When you drag yellow, it changes the rest for track liker you see.

[image]

What i want is to set two colors, when you drag the button from center, track colors will not change and stay 50:50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution i found is to create an `Image` or `View` with `absolute position`, and put it behind the `Slider` with `ZIndex -1`.

Slider was set to transparent `minum` and `maximum Track`.